PDF for Bates Distribution from Three Uniform Distributions
I am attempting to calculate the exact PDF for Bates distribution from three uniform distributions (n=3). I am attempting to do this by convolving the n=2 bates PDF solution with another uniform distribution. Putting the problem into words:
Given:

Definition of convolution: $$f*g=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)g(x-t) \,dt $$
The uniform distribution: $$
g(x)=\Biggl\{ \begin{align*} \frac{1}{a},\quad\frac{-a}{2}\le x \le \frac{a}{2}\\0,\qquad otherwise \end{align*}
$$
Bates PDF for n=2, which is a triangular distribution: $$
f(x)=\Biggl\{ \begin{align*} \frac{4x}{a^2}+\frac{2}{a},\quad\frac{-a}{2}\le x \le 0 \\\frac{-4x}{a^2}+\frac{2}{a},\quad0\lt x \le \frac{a}{2}\\
0,\qquad otherwise  \end{align*}
$$

Find:
$f*g$
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are independent, symmetric, and centered at $x=0$. The variable $a$ is used to define the span of the distributions.  I need help setting up the integrals and figuring out the domain for integration for this problem. I have attempted to do it on my own, and I end up with a distribution that is too broad and not tall enough compared to the correct solution.
I have been able to find the exact solution numerically using the Octave $conv()$ function. I've verified the solution is correct by comparing it to a sample distribution produced using random numbers. As shown in the figure below, the results agree quite well (Note: a=200 in the figure).
Comparison of numerical solution and sampled distribution.
However, I would still like to be able to arrive at the exact solution analytically in order to calculate the exact values for the confidence intervals.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.
